# adding 'PyLit' pure python module on OS X

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-module

I'm trying to add a module to my PYTHONPATH permanently, I know this could sound like a duplicated question, but I tried all the solution that i could find.

what I want to do is:

- add PyLit module (https://github.com/gmilde/PyLit) to my PYTHONPATH permanently.

the instructions to install it are:

```
Install
As PyLit is a pure Python module, installation is straightforward: Put pylit.py in Python's Module Search Path.
```

I need this module to be added permanently. I tried:

- adding it in my .bash_profile in my $PATH
- creating in my .bash_profile a $PYTHONPATH new var
- adding it to my: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
- tried using [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/) (and [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip))

I'm a newbie with Python, but I have given a look at the module I want to add, and the structure seems weerd, usually I use a setup.py file but it is missing.

```
python setup.py install
```

I hope someone can help me out...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue... There were conflicts between ma python versions. I basically removed python 2.7 and reinstalled it.

Then I tried again with the pip approach and, **after rebooting my mac book pro**, everything worked just fine.